# Detect object completely inside another object

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, fabricjs, intersection, bounding-box

Good day everyone,

I was wondering if there was a way to detect if a fabric object is COMPLETELY inside another object?

I was looking at `object.intersectsWithObject(object2)` in the documentation but unfortunately, as soon as the object is completely inside object2, the function doesn't give back true anymore but false.

Has someone else had this problem? I am do not know at all how to do this.
I have searched for the function in fabric.js. Can someone help?

```
    intersectsWithObject: function(other) {
  // extracts coords
  function getCoords(oCoords) {
    return {
      tl: new fabric.Point(oCoords.tl.x, oCoords.tl.y),
      tr: new fabric.Point(oCoords.tr.x, oCoords.tr.y),
      bl: new fabric.Point(oCoords.bl.x, oCoords.bl.y),
      br: new fabric.Point(oCoords.br.x, oCoords.br.y)
    };
  }
  var thisCoords = getCoords(this.oCoords),
      otherCoords = getCoords(other.oCoords),
      intersection = fabric.Intersection.intersectPolygonPolygon(
        [thisCoords.tl, thisCoords.tr, thisCoords.br, thisCoords.bl],
        [otherCoords.tl, otherCoords.tr, otherCoords.br, otherCoords.bl]
      );

  return intersection.status === 'Intersection';
}
```

Thank you already for your help
Sebastian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know if an abject is completely inside another object you should use [**isContainedWithinObject**](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#isContainedWithinObject):

> **isContainedWithinObject(other)** → {**Boolean**}
>
> § Checks if object is fully
>   contained within area of another object
>
> Parameters:
>
> **Name** : other
>   **Type**: Object
>
> **Description**: Object to test
>
> Source: fabric.js,
>   line 12300
>
> Returns: true if object is fully contained within area of
>   another object
>
> **Type**: Boolean

This is the source:

```
isContainedWithinObject: function(other) {
      var boundingRect = other.getBoundingRect(),
          point1 = new fabric.Point(boundingRect.left, boundingRect.top),
          point2 = new fabric.Point(boundingRect.left + boundingRect.width, boundingRect.top + boundingRect.height);

      return this.isContainedWithinRect(point1, point2);
    }
```

It works using the bounding box of the object you would test.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for every combination of 'inside' and 'inner' but didn't check 'within'. Thanks and sorry! Might help others in the future though.